# How to split and change the json format

Tags: php, json, slim

I am using slimphp v2 and I have the following function

```
function gt($user) {
    $sql = "select id, id as categoryId, mobile, task from actions where status=0";
    try {
        $db = newDB($user);
        $stmt = $db - > prepare($sql);
        $stmt - > execute();
        $gs = $stmt - > fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if ($gs) {
            $db = null;
            echo json_encode($gs, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        } else {
            echo "Not Found";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e - > getMessage().
        '}}';
    }
}
```

The default json output looks like:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "categoryId": "1",
    "mobile": "111",
    "task": "test"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "mobile": "222",
    "task": "test2"
}]
```

and the output that i am trying to make. I need to generate an ID: 1_(id) then format it like this

```
[{
    id: "1",
    task: "test",
}, {
    ID: "1_1", //generate this, add 1_id
    categoryId: "1",
    mobile: "00000",
},  {
    id: "2",
    task: "test2",
}, {
    ID: "1_2", //generate this, add 1_id
    categoryId: "2",
    mobile: "11111"
}];
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what your after but you can gain the desired JSON output by converting your original JSON into an associative array and then restructure the data on each iteration using a `Foreach()` loop into a new assoc array. After that, you can just convert it back to JSON using `json_encode()`.

**Code:**

```
$json = '[{
    "id": "1",
    "categoryId": "1",
    "mobile": "111",
    "task": "test"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "mobile": "222",
    "task": "test2"
}]';

$jsonArr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$newArr = [];

foreach ($jsonArr as $v) {

    $newArr[] = ['id:'=>$v['id'], 'task:' => $v['task']];
    $newArr[] = ['ID:'=>'1_' . $v['id'], 'categoryId' => $v['categoryId'], 'mobile'=>$v['mobile']];  

}

$newJson = json_encode($newArr);
var_dump($newJson);
```

**Output:**

```
[{
    "id:": "1",
    "task:": "test"
}, {
    "ID:": "1_1",
    "categoryId": "1",
    "mobile": "111"
}, {
    "id:": "2",
    "task:": "test2"
}, {
    "ID:": "1_2",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "mobile": "222"
}]
```

***Edit -- Updated Answer***

As discussed in comments, your outputting your SQL array as an object. I've set the Fetch to output as an associative array using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and changed the `foreach()` loop to reference the assoc array `$gs`. This should work but if not then output your results for `$gs` again using `var_dump($gs)`. You will still need to encode to JSON if needed but this line has been commented out.

```
function gt($user) {
    $sql = "select id, id as categoryId, mobile, task from actions where status=0";
        try {
                $db = newDB($user);
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $gs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Fetch as Associative Array

                if ($gs) {

                    $db = null;
                    $newArr = [];

                    foreach ($gs as $v) { //$gs Array should still work with foreach loop

                        $newArr[] = ['id:'=>$v['id'], 'task:' => $v['task']];
                        $newArr[] = ['ID:'=>'1_' . $v['id'], 'categoryId' => $v['categoryId'], 'mobile'=>$v['mobile']];

                    }

                    //$newJson = json_encode($newArr); //JSON encode here if you want it converted to JSON.




                } else {

                 echo "Not Found";

                }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
                echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }
}
```

Comment: If you comment out my code and var_dump($gs); do you get the JSON output? Can you put the JSON in your question (edit anything confidential)

Comment: I can see what the issue is, your trying to `json_decode()` and object which is not JSON. To test, if you add `$gs = json_encode($gs);` as the first line in your `if()` statement, the object will then json_decode and should complete. Obviously this is not a fix so let me know if that works.

Comment: Okey let me try

Comment: I've updated my answer to match your code. See explanation for full understanding and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yeah works like a charm in this way!Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries and glad it's sorted :-)